# How to drag and drop a UIButton

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, drag-and-drop, uitouch

I have four UIButtons in my interface file. I have outlets attached to each button. I want to be able to drag and drop them across the screen. What is the best way to do this? How can I do this? please help!!!

Comment: Hover the mouse over the button, hold down the mouse button, and move the mouse.

Comment: I think he meant from within the app.

Comment: Apple's [Touches sample app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

try this u can drag and drop your button what ever you want

implement this code in `ViewDidLoad`

```
 [self.shoeimageOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [self.shoeimageOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
```

it will call the method written below

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIControl *control = sender;
    control.center = point;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibilities nowadays on how to enable items – that is UIViews and UIControls – to be draggable.

- override touchesMoved
- add a target/selector for dragging control events
- add a pan gesture recognizer

[The complete tutorial found here !!!](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/11/draggable-buttons-labels/)